# Applying to a PhD program 12 years after completing an MS degree

Tags: phd, application

I have finally found a PhD program that appeals to me based on my work history and research interests. There is a potential problem, though, in that the program wants at least one academic reference--but I graduated with my M.S. in 2008.

The head of the program indicated it would be acceptable for me to apply without any academic references, but they would prefer I have one from my thesis advisor if possible. This isn't possible, as I've tried over the years to reach out and say hello and maintain the connection, but he eventually just started ignoring my emails. The one upside is that I do work as a researcher in industry, and I have journal and industry publications, as well as speaking engagements I can point to.

Would it be better in such a scenario to go back and try to reconnect to my advisor? Or would applying in for the MS program alone be better?

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: Is there any chance you could make an "in person" visit and request?

Comment: Is there any person in contact with you former advisor, whom you could contact instead? Is there any person who is familiar with your industry job and happens to be an academic?(maybe just to check if the former advisor is alive and didn't change his email) Do you have any personal friend who is an academic? As long as the relationships are clear in the letters, you seem to have plenty of options left.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. Visiting in person won't be possible, unfortunately.

Comment: I do know a few people in my field who have PhDs, but they didn't supervise any of my work, so I don't think they could provide an accurate assessment. I do not have a personal friend who is an academic, either. At the moment I am taking courses as a student-at-large hoping that would provide me with a connection or two for a recommendation letter, but they stated specifically that they would not accept recommendation letters from staff unless I had attended undergrad at the school (which I did not).